# Generic Interfaces for ICustomerRetList and ICustomerRet - QBFC

Tags: qbfc

Any QBFC developers out there?  I'm using QBFC to pull multiple different types of objects out of Quickbooks:  Customers, Items, Invoices, TaxCodes, etc.  The data query code really only varies once you get to the Ret object so I'm trying to build some functions to abstract the process.

A typical repose object looks like

```
IReponseList
    IResponse
         RetList
             Ret
```

IResponseList and IResponse are both generic enough to work on all query response types.  However, there doesn't appear to be a generic RetList and Ret Interface that I can use for the abstraction.  I only have type-sepecific interfaces like ICustomerRetList, ISalesTaxCodeRetList, etc.  I'd like to write the code independent of what TYPE of return list it is....

Is there an interface for RetList or Ret that I just can't seem to find?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface `IQBBase` is the closest thing to what you're looking for. Most everything in QBFC is derived from `IQBase`, including all query types and all return types. Using `IQBBase` references and .NET generics it is possible to create a framework to deal with query results.

**Update:** the iterator example below is now available as part of the Zombie library for QBFC, which you can [grab from github](https://github.com/pkpjpm/Zombie).

For example, here's a generic iterator that takes the RetList type and Ret type as parameters:

```
/// <summary>
/// This generic class simplifies and standardizes iteration syntax
/// for QBFC lists.  Using this class we can use the foreach keyword
/// to iterate across all items in a list.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="L">The type of the list, for example IBillRetList</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="D">The type of the item, for example IBillRet</typeparam>
public class QBFCIterator<L, D>:IEnumerable<D> where L : class, IQBBase
{

    private L m_List;

    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor can be used for response list items or for sub-lists that are properties
    /// on other QBFC objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lst">The sub-list</param>
    public QBFCIterator(IQBBase lst)
    {
        m_List = lst as L;

        if (m_List == null && lst != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("iterator type mismatch");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_List == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return Count == 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An efficient alternative to the Count() function
    /// </summary>
    public int EntityCount
    {
        get { return Count; }
    }

    public D GetFirstItem()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot retrieve item from empty list");
        }
        else
        {
            return GetAt(0);
        }
    }        

    #region Late-bound properties
    //
    // Since .NET requires that all methods invoked on a parameterized type
    // must compile based solely on interface constraints, we must use late
    // binding to access the count property and GetAt methods.  This may have 
    // an impact on performance and could conceivably cause run time errors 
    // with incorrect type parameters.
    //
    private int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_List == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Type t = m_List.GetType();

                return (int)t.InvokeMember("Count",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, m_List, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private D GetAt(int idx)
    {
        Type t = m_List.GetType();

        return (D)t.InvokeMember("GetAt", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, m_List, new Object[] { idx });
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<D> Members

    public IEnumerator<D> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (m_List != null)
        {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < Count; idx++)
            {
                yield return GetAt(idx);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (m_List != null)
        {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < Count; idx++)
            {
                yield return GetAt(idx);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```